# Showing cells with zero instances of a factor in a summary table instead of omitting them

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Say we have a data frame with two variables `var1` and `var2`, each a factor with two levels

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(var1 = factor(sample(c("A", "B"), 20, replace = T)),
                 var2 = factor(rep(c("C","D"), each = 10)))
```

When we summarise this dataframe

```
df %>% group_by(var1, var2) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

We get

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   var1 [?]
  var1  var2  count
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 A     C         5
2 A     D         4
3 B     C         5
4 B     D         6
```

But if we remove all instances of one factor

```
df2 <- df[1:10,]
```

And summarise

```
df2 %>% group_by(var1, var2) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

We get

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   var1 [?]
  var1  var2  count
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 A     C         5
2 B     C         5
```

The `A-D` and `B-D` cells are (unsurprisingly) not summarised because there are no longer any instances in these cells.

My question is **is there any quick way to report these cells as 0 instead of omitting them from the summary table?**

I know the `D` level of `var2` is still embedded in that factor in `df2` because

```
str(df2)
```

yields

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1
 $ var2: Factor w/ 2 levels "C","D": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

So how do I get `dplyr` to report the 0 cells as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `complete` along with `ungroup` (without it we would get too many combinations):

```
df2 %>% group_by(var1, var2) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  complete(var1, var2, fill = list(count = 0))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   var1  var2  count
#   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
# 1 A     C         3
# 2 A     D         0
# 3 B     C         7
# 4 B     D         0
```

or `complete` and `distinct`:

```
df2 %>% group_by(var1, var2) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>%
  complete(var1, var2, fill = list(count = 0)) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   var1  var2  count
#   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
# 1 A     C         3
# 2 A     D         0
# 3 B     C         7
# 4 B     D         0
```

Comment: Nice - if you make it, `fill=list(count=0L)` the `count` will stay as an integer.

Comment: @Julius Vainora, I think `complete()` has made my life complete. Thank you!